# How to show/hide elements in View based on user's permissions got clientside in JSON?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, security, user-permissions

I have a JSON that brings me set of users-roles, which define for me what actions the user can perform or not.

The JSON loads in the client side. I want to hide elements on this page using serverside code and not clientside, cause this approach is safer and un open to hacks.

```
//.Net MVC Code
if (!userCanDelete){
    //don't print the selector to the page
}
```

Is it possible in *.Net MVC 2* to do that?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Just check for the user's privileges.

Comment: We don't use user privileges object of Net.

Answer (score 2):

I do the same thing in my app, with a **custom HTML helper**.

Personally I get specific rights for specific guys and specific actions during the login.

I get this rights serverside (*it's safer!*) from a JSON.

I store this rights in the session and use it in my custom helper:

```
public static class HtmlHelperCustom
{
    public static bool IsAccessibleToUser(this HtmlHelper helper, String element)
    {
        var user = (UserModel)HttpContext.Current.Session["currentUser"];

        return user.rights.Contains(element);
    }
}
```

Then in my View, I just call the helper with the element:

```
@{ 
    if (Html.IsAccessibleToUser("urlUpdate"))
    {
        <a href="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.urlUpdate)" target="_blank">
            <i class="icon-wrench" title="update">&nbsp;</i>
        </a>
    }
}
```

You should get JSON serverside or modify my solution slightly.